# What do you suggest to make undo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use a series of data as follows:

```
[
  {
    name: 'name1',
    background:'red',
    child:[
        {
          name:'',
          id:'',
          color:'',
          text:'',
          border:''
          
        },
        {
          name:'',
          id:'',
          color:'',
          text:'',
          border:''
          
        }
      
      
      ]
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    background:'red',
    child:[
        {
          name:'',
          id:'',
          color:'',
          text:'',
          border:''
          
        },
        {
          name:'',
          id:'',
          color:'',
          text:'',
          border:''
          
        }
      
      
      ]
  }
  
  ]
```

I'm going to save all the changes to another variable, and I used a deep copy to do that, but when I log in, the variables are the same.I need to children all the children changes too.

**I wrote it in Reducers**

```
const Reducers =(state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case NEW_OBJECTS_PAST:

            const OldPast = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.past))
            const newDate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.present))
            // const newDate = _.cloneDeep(state.present);

            const newPast = [
                                OldPast,
                                newDate
                            ];
            return {
                ...state,
                past : _.cloneDeep(newPast) ,
            }

        case OBJECTS:

            
            return  {
                        ...state,
                        present: action.objects,
                        // future:[]
            }
```

Do you suggest another way to build undo in **REACT** and **REDUX** ?
I tried the libraries available for this, but got no answer.

Answer (score 1):

First two remarks :

- you should never deep clone parts of your state, it doesn't bring you any benefits as the state is immutable anyway, but is very detrimental for memory usage and for performance (both when doing the deep cloning and then when using the deep cloned state),
- you should use Redux toolkit, which makes it way easier to write immutable reducers and prevent many errors.

To implement undo, I'm not sure what your actions are supposed to mean but you can do it as follows

- the state contains `state.present` (the current state) and `state.past` (an array of past states)
- whenever you do an action that you want to undo, you push the current `state.present` at the end of `state.past` and compute the new `state.present`
- whenever you want to undo, you pop the last element of `state.past` and put it in `state.present`.

In your code I can't see any undo action, and you're also building nested arrays because of `new Past = [oldPast, new Date]`, you most likely meant to spread `oldPast`.